# How can we develop custom themes in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

i am working on theming concepts in SAPUI5 application.

I got to know that the theming can be done by using UI Theme Designer (which is a tool in SAP backend).

I got to know this from [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/09/19/create-and-apply-custom-theme-to-sapui5-application).

Is it possible to develop a custom theme in SAPUI5 with out using Theme Designer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a range of options, Theme Designer being the easiest and least flexible one, a completely written-from scratch CSS file the other extreme.
In between there are options like copying an existing theme, renaming it, and appending CSS parts that modify the existing appearance (this is also possible in Theme Designer!).

One main deciding factor is how different your theme should look from an existing one, and what your upgrade strategy is. Very different themes might be best created using the "base" theme as... well, base. But whenever you create lots of extra CSS you need to be aware that you have to adapt it to new UI5 releases. The Theme Designer does this automatically, as long as you don't add any custom CSS.

Before writing a theme from scratch or vastly modifying one, you should look at how large existing themes are and estimate whether you want and can develop and maintain such a thing on your own.
(Why are they so complex? 200 controls - and that's only the OpenUI5 subset - and many of them very powerful with different appearances and responsiveness, working across devices, and also appearing in right-to-left mode,... that's something no other framework offers, so of course the UI5 themes are larger than those of much smaller frameworks.)